# VS Code не перекомпилирует проект asp.net после изменения и сохранения файлов .cs

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

В документации пишут, что VS после изменения в запущенном стартовом проекте кода

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
```

на код

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World new!");
        });
```

с последующим сохранением файла и обновлением страницы в браузере без перезапуска проекта должна выдавать в браузер строку Hello World new!, но этого не происходит, выводится предыдущая строка. Как включить опцию обновления приложения без перезапуска?

Comment: Как запускается приложение: через IIS или само по себе? В "большой" Студии (не Code) в свойствах проекта вкладка Debug > Launch > IIS/Project: если задать IIS, то работает как вы хотите. Как это задается в Code - не в курсе.

Comment: Отладка в Kestrel.